# postgresql typeOrm filter manyToMany relation

Tags: typescript, postgresql, many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

i have 2 entities with ManyToMany relation:

```
//branch entity
 @ManyToMany(
        (type) => User,
        (e) => e.branches
    )
    users: User[];


//user entity
   @ManyToMany(
        (type) => Branch,
        (e) => e.users,
        {   eager: true,
            cascade: false }
    )
    
    @JoinTable()
    branches: Branch[];


    @IsEnum(Role)
    @Column('text', { default: Role.Client })
    role: Role;
```

I want to find branches if users list not contain user with role 'client'.

i need this, if i have:

```
[
 Branch {
    id: '98007770-c924-43cd-988c-774492e1e759',
    name: 'poslovnica1',
    users: [ {role:'client'},{role:'superAdmin'} ]
  },
 Branch {
    id: '787007770-c924-43cd-988c-774492e1e759',
    name: 'poslovnica13',
    users: [ {role:'client'},{role:'superAdmin'} ]
  },

  Branch {
    id: '36f5b1ad-6553-4b2f-936b-33fb4ca8e73e',
    name: 'poslovnica2',
    users: [ {role:'superAdmin' }]
  }
]
```

after filter i want to get, all branches if they not have  user with
role 'client'. 'superAdmin' or :

```
[
   Branch {
    id: '36f5b1ad-6553-4b2f-936b-33fb4ca8e73e',
    name: 'poslovnica2',
    users: [ {role:'superAdmin'} ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow !

You were close to it indeed !
I'd give it a try with the following piece of code (using lodash):

```js
import {values, omit} from 'lodash';

// ....

const notClientRoles = values(omit(Role, Role.Client));

await this.branchRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('b')
    .leftJoin('b.users', 'users')
    .where('users.client IN(:...roles)', { roles: notClientRoles })
    .getMany();
```

Details:

```js
const notClientRoles = values(omit(Role, Role.Client))
```

is used to remove the `Client` role from the ones you want (we use `values` and `omit` methods from `lodash`). We wrap it in a variable and then use it in our `where` clause, like this:

```js
    .where('users.client IN(:...roles)', { roles: notClientRoles })
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: i try like you say, but i need something else

Answer (score 0):

i get same result like you try with lodash, but in another way:

```
await branchRepository.find({
                    join: {
                        alias: 'branch',
                        leftJoinAndSelect: {
                            users: 'branch.users'
                        }
                    },
                    where: (qb) => {
                        qb.where('role != :role', { role: 'client' });
                    }
                });
```

but i need to filter branches by users, not users... Thanks for try!

Answer (score 0):

i get what i want:

```
 retVal = await this.branchRepository.find({ relations: ['users'] });
 retVal = retVal.filter((branch: Branch) => {
                if (!branch.users.some((user) => user.role === Role.Client)) return branch;
                });
```

but i looking to improve this if is posible...